# Javascript use the output of a function as their own input

Tags: javascript, recursion, logic

I wrote an nice function which takes 5 of 14 randoms Pics an put it in 5 of 10 random Positions this runs perfectly.

The function is call every x seconds (x = 5 or whatever else ;-)

my code:

```
var done = false;
var interval = 1000;
$(document).ready(function() 
{   
    var mytime =    setInterval(function(){
        if (done)
        { 
            done = false;
        }
        else
        {
            clearPics();
            var oldPics = makePics();
            console.log(oldPics);
            done = true;
        }

    },interval);

});
```

Now I need  in the next run 5 new pictures which are NOT this 5 of 14.
There has to be 5 other ones.

My plan is to get the array of the first (n=>1) run (call Var oldPics)
and check within the function makePics()
if the the numbers of the Picture are in the first run (n-1 when n is greater than one) .

I need something like

```
var oldPics = makePics();
makePics(oldPics);
```

without calling the function makePics() two times

Is there any possibility to do this?

Comment: What does makePics do? Post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like that:

```
var done = false;
var interval = 1000;
$(document).ready(function() 
{   

    var myPics;

    var mytime =    setInterval(function(){
        if (done)
        { 
            done = false;
        }
        else
        {
            clearPics();
            myPics = makePics(myPics);
            done = true;
        }

    },interval);

});
```

So, in **makePics()** function you can check if the paramerters **myPics** is empty (first call) or have something (second call)

If I understood correctly you need something like that, right?

Comment: Yess :-)
Very nice this runs.
Thank You :-)

Comment: happy to hear that :)